# Disable swipe in DrawerLayoutAndroid

Tags: reactjs, react-native, drawerlayout

I am using DrawerLayoutAndroid in my project. I would like to disable the swipe feature on Drawer so in that case it should not open on close on swipe. How could that be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add this prop to your DrawerLayoutAndroid component:

```
drawerLockMode = 'locked-closed'
```

The above code will not allow your drawer component to respond to any gesture

Cheers:)